# Laravel & Beanstalkd - File Copy / Download Error

Tags: php, file, laravel, queue, beanstalkd

I'm using Laravel 4 and am trying out queues with Beanstalkd (running on Homestead locally)

I have a script which downloads and parses an XML file which is working fine with the sync driver but when I switch to the beanstalkd driver I get a `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` error on the `copy()` function.

Is there any configuration that I might be overlooking with file downloading via Beanstalkd?  I get the same error whether I'm trying to `copy()` a URL or a local file so I assume it's not network related.  I also tried `fopen()` but get the same error. It works fine however for simple tasks such as `Log::info('This works.');`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when running Artisan tasks... the problem was with the file paths.  Laravel was automatically resolving paths to the public directory but Beanstalkd & Artisan were not.  Adding `public_path()` before `'/folder/file.txt'` solved the issue.